# How to disable button after 2 clicks using jQuery when counter is running on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have the below counter runs on page load

```js
if ($k('#Passcode').is(':visible')) {
  $('.input').removeAttr('required');
  var counter = 60;
  
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    
    if (counter <= 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('#timer').empty();
      $('#btnResend').removeClass('disabled');
      return;
    } 
    else {
      $('#time').text('Resend code in ' + counter);
    }
  }, 1000);

  $("#btnSubmitOTP").click(function() {
    if ($('#codeBox1').val() !== '' &&
      $('#codeBox2').val() !== '' &&
      $('#codeBox3').val() !== '' &&
      $('#codeBox4').val() !== '' &&
      $('#codeBox5').val() !== '' &&
      $('#codeBox6').val() !== '' &&
      $('#codeBox7').val() !== '') {
      mainSubmitClick();
    }
  });
```

The below code is for when clicked on resend button , then otp will get triggered.

```js
$("#btnResend").click(function() {
  $k('#errorcode').val('');
  $k('#servicetype').val("SENDOTP");
  mainSubmitClick();
  return false;
});
```

When user clicked the resend button on 2nd time, then the message should show as "Maximum resend limit reached" .

So i tried the below jQuery but the problem is , the message "Maximum resend limit reached" is showing after the 1st click itself. And the resend button gets disabled.

```js
var count = 0;

$("#btnResend").click(function() {
  if (++count > 1)
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    
  clearInterval(interval);
  $('#timer').text('Maximum resend limit reached!');
  counter = 0;
  $('#time').hide();
  ('#btnSubmitOTP').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: @Reporter :  Two single clicks . i.e., in the first resend the otp will get triggered and after this if the user clicked on the resend button then the message should show. And in this case the otp should get triggered.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable example?